# Syntax highlighting indicates I'm unable to comment properly in Mathematica using (**)

Tags: bugs, syntax, syntax-highlighting, comment

I wanted to "comment" some code so the input inside [`(* *)`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TheSyntaxOfTheWolframLanguage.html) is ignored.

I tried this but the last term `z[3]` looks like it is not commented.

```
 (* z[1]=1; z[2]=2; z[3]=3; *)
```

[image: mathematica editor]

**How to rectify this?**

I know it is a simple question, but I didn't find the answer to this.

Comment: I'd say that it is not expected but there are known problems with syntax highlighting, usually can be fixed by cut+paste or adding a space here and there. Btw, it seems that is not a standard stylesheet, which one it that?

Comment: I used default style sheet but I have changed the background color to light green

Answer (score 5):

Your comments are fine, if in doubt always check the [`FullForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm.html) of the expresion.
The problem is only in the syntax highlighting, that has been far from perfect in most version.

```
FullForm[(*z[1]=1;z[2]=2;z[3]=3;*) z]
(* z *)
```

As this is a bug, you may avoid it but not rectify this problem unless *Wolfram* releases a patched version of *Mathematica*. Next time it happens take a screenshot go to *Help > Give feedback*, and fill a report to Wolfram Support.

[image]